# Angular/2 : angular2-select populate from observable

Tags: angular

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-select package. I'm trying to populate the select tag with the value of "tagOptions" which is populated as follows:

I'm subscribing to an observable and formatting the returned data in the subscribe as follows:

```
/**
 * Load all available tags
 */
private getTags() : void {

    // The observable
    this.tagService.tags$
    .subscribe( (tags) => {

        for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {

            this.tagOptions.push({ value: tags[i].id, label: tags[i].name });
        }

        this.variantForm.patchValue({
            tags: this.tagOptions
        });            
    });

    let criteria = {columns: ['id','name']};
    // Make an ajax request and populate the observable
    this.tagService.load(this.utilityService.encode(criteria))
    .subscribe();
}
```

My template reads as

```
<ng-select
    [options]="tagOptions"
    placeholder="Select one"
    multiple="true"
    allowClear="true"
    formControlName="tags">
</ng-select>
```

My template bombs out on page load with

"core.umd.js:3462 EXCEPTION: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined"

I suspect my approach to populating the select is incorrect. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This is probably an async problem. What happens when you provide dummy data for `this.tagOptions`? Does the `ng-select` update when the subscription returns data?

Comment: Hi @Federico. I suspect async as well. The select populates correctly with dummy data, it's when i try and patch the value it bombs out. Is it possible ng-select does not support reactive forms? I don't pretend to understand Angular well enough to know.

Comment: Hmmm. It's possible. What happens when you don't do the patchvalue? this.tagOptions is bound to [options] so maybe it's unecessary.

Comment: Removed the patch statement and nothing happens, the options are never updated. beginning to think it's a limitation of the solution.

Comment: True. What you could do is have the data available to your template right when the page loads, using the `resolve` router guard. It prevents your page from loading before your subscription returns data. (That way you're not stuck with useless dummy data). Read more about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard)

Comment: Looks to be the solution I need, thanks! If you scribble an answer I shall flag as correct. Once again, many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<ng-select>` seems to not reflect changes to its `[options]` input after it has been rendered. To get around this, you'll need to have the data ready to go before the `<ng-select>` is rendered. The angular route guard '`resolve`' function does exactly that. If you make the resolve function wait on a subscription, then the page will not be rendered until the data is available.

Link to [Router `resolve` guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard).

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

With ng-select (as angular2-select is now called) you can pass an observable and add  `| async` to your options as such:

```
<ng-select
    [options]="tagOptions | async"
    placeholder="Select one"
    multiple="true"
    allowClear="true"
    formControlName="tags">
</ng-select>
```

This seems to work better.

See https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-sources